# Does __bin__ (or __binary__) operator exists in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, operators

In Python, the `__oct__` and `__hex__` operators exists to implement specific bahavior for `oct()` and `hex()`. See [Emulating numeric types](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html?#object.__oct__)

But I don’t understand why `__bin__` (or `__binary__`) doesn’t exist, whereas `bin()` function exists in the built-ins. See [Built-in Functions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bin).

Am I missing something? Any reason?

### Changes in Python 3

I have found this reference [Operators And Special Methods](https://docs.python.org/3.5/whatsnew/3.0.html?operators-and-special-methods) in "What’s New In Python 3.0":

> The **oct**() and **hex**() special methods are removed – oct() and hex() use **index**() now to convert the argument to an integer.

Comment: [`object.__index__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?#object.__index__) is called for `bin()` in both Python 2 and 3. Though it is not seem to be documented for Python 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`object.__index__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html?#object.__index__) to handle `bin()` calls in Python 2. From Python 3 onwards it works for `hex()` and `oct()` as well but not in Python 2.

From [Python 3 docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?#object.__index__):

> `object.__index__(self)`
>
> Called to implement `operator.index()`, and whenever Python needs to
>   losslessly convert the numeric object to an integer object (such as in
>   slicing, or in the built-in `bin()`, `hex()` and `oct()` functions).
>   Presence of this method indicates that the numeric object is an
>   integer type. Must return an integer.

It is not documented(clearly) in Python 2 but works there as well:

```
>>> class A(object):
...     def __index__(self):
...         return 100
...
>>> bin(A())
'0b1100100'
```

The CPython code for [`bin()`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Python/bltinmodule.c#l219) internally calls [`PyNumber_ToBase`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Objects/abstract.c#l1819) which in turn calls [`PyNumber_Index`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Objects/abstract.c#l1490) and this function invokes the `nb_index` slot on that object.

Comment: Ok, this is a Python 2 inconsistency which is solved in Python 3.

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE Yeah, core devs basically decided the remove the two extra slots `nb_hex` and `nb_oct` in favour of single `nb_index` to make things simpler.

Comment: Note: You can use `__index__` consistently in Python 2 too, by doing `from future_builtins import oct, hex` to get the Py3 versions of those functions.